# Secure WebSocket fail to connection - 1001 server error

Tags: javascript, delphi, ssl, websocket

I have create a simple WebSocket server with ssl certificate (self signed).
This server is created in Delphi.
If I try to connect on this server with Delphi client application the connection works.
If I try to connect on server with html5/javascript program, the server return the error "1001-Going Away"
The javascript program works with address "ws://localhost:777/" (and a server without TLS logic) but don't work with "wss://localhost:777/" address.

I paste a program code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>WebSocket Test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = "wss://localhost:777/";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

</script>

<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Please, can you explain why this situation happen and how can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: which client and server WebSocket library for Delphi are you using?

Comment: who provides TLS, ip*works directly, or is a reverse proxy (Apache) between client and server?

Comment: ip*works load the certificate and provide TLS. No Apache in the middle.